# unable to run snyk via node using bash wrapper script

Tags: node.js, npm, terraform, devops, snyk

I was able to run the iac scanner via [snyk](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360003812578-CLI-reference) using these commands:

```
$ npm install -g snyk
$ snyk auth my-hash-api-token-key
$ snyk iac test /path/to/my/terraform.tf
```

I tried to wrapped those commands into one bash script using this format

```
#!/bin/bash
token=$1
directory=$2

echo "PERFORMING SNYK SCAN"

echo "INSTALL SNYK"
npm install -g snyk

echo "AUTHENTICATE TO SNYK PORTAL"
snyk auth ${token}

echo "PERFORM SNYK TEST"
snyk iac test ${directory}
```

However I always got this result from terminal = **/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory** and looking to a **package.json**
Sample output when executing the wrapper script below:

```
$ pwd
/home/user

$ ls -ltrh
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 59 Feb 22 08:55 terraform-files

$ my-wrapper-script.sh my-hash-api-token-key /home/user/terraform-files
PERFORMING SNYK SCAN

INSTALL SNYK
/usr/bin/snyk -> /usr/lib/node_modules/snyk/dist/cli/index.js
+ snyk@1.458.0
updated 1 package in 11.49s

AUTHENTICATE TO SNYK PORTAL
Authenticating

PERFORM SNYK TEST 
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
npm WARN SOURCE_REPO_FOLDER No description
npm WARN SOURCE_REPO_FOLDER No repository field.
npm WARN SOURCE_REPO_FOLDER No README data
npm WARN SOURCE_REPO_FOLDER No license field.

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

**PS: I also tried the suggested solutions I found on other articles like creating sym link on nodejs and node but that is not applicable cause I already have node on my box. I still have limited knowledge in npm/node. My goal is to make the scanning work**

Comment: What's the output of the 3 following commands? `which node`, `echo $PATH`, `bash -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: which node shows - /usr/bin/node

Comment: echo $PATH and bash -c 'echo $PATH' shows - /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas. I tried to repro in a `node:14` docker image but it worked just fine.

Comment: np @MaxIvanov I'm also researching and testing on this

Comment: Tested your script on my Manjaro machine, having no issues either.

Comment: Like others, I am unable to duplicate your issue.  Also of note, for automation purposes, some prefer to set the SNYK_TOKEN env var before the `snyk test` command rather than run `snyk auth` repetitively.

Comment: @Lagot, are you still seeing the issue?

Comment: @EricSmalling yes I'm still having this issue

Comment: @Lagot, did you resolve it? The issue is 2 years old, it may have been a environment problem; however Snyk also released a few new CLI versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for I lost track, this has been resolved. We have removed the snyk from the wrapper script and use a different approach of running it. We can close this